# Connection timeout error when launching my program from a shortcut

Tags: connection-timeout, access-denied

I'm seeing connection timeout errors when I launch my program from a shortcut.

The error appears when I start the windows application:

> error found !! timeout expired. the timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the server is not responding

but if I copy folder from `c:/program file/myapplication` and paste it on `D:/` drive and start the application it works fine, but not from start menu and desktop shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your program is getting database connection settings from a file which is in the same folder as the program, and your code is just assuming it will find this file in the current directory. When it is unable to read the settings, it tries to connect using invalid connection settings.

The quickest fix is to right-click the shortcut, select Properties, and change the Working Folder to the program folder.

The better (longer to implement) solution is to either:

- Have your program check the folder your program is in and specify the full path when opening your configuration file
- Store settings in the registry

Answer (score -1):

Go to run pressing "winkey +r" and write 'msconfig' and check in the Startup applications. If you find myapplication in the list then just disable it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question

Comment: But when i answered this question, the question and description seemed to be something else.